# How do I keep 2 EFS instances in sync across regions

Tags: sync, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, efs

My company has an application running with multiple EC2 instances sharing 1 EFS instance that holds our application's files in the US East region, however our application is used nationally and our west coast clients are experiencing latency issues. So we have started the process of setting up EC2 instances in the US West region.

Unfortunately, EFS instances cannot be shared across regions so that means that we now have to manually make sure these instances stay in sync. It is critical to our application that the files between the 2 EFS instances always match; so an automated solution is needed.

**My Question:** What is the best way I can automate keeping 2 EFS instances in sync across multiple regions?

Comment: Technically, you can use EFS across regions using VPC peering and an HAProxy in the region where EFS is deployed, [described here](https://serverfault.com/a/799213/153161)... it's just not *officially* supported or endorsed.  I've been doing this for quite some time, with no issues... other than the obvious latency issues accessing a filesystem over distance.  Unless/until EFS provides trigger "hooks" for changed content, or someone writes an NFS-aware proxy to capture them on the wire (an idea I have considered but have not done anything about, so far) I don't think this is practical.

Comment: Of course, you might also find that routing access to your application through CloudFront improves the perceived latency significantly enough to avoid architectural changes.  The DNS response returns addresses from an "edge location" near the viewer, which proxies the request over the AWS network back to the nearest region and from there back to your home region, often improving performance and throughput (not to mention that it goes past a cache at the edge and another at the first region, either of which can return cached responses if available).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Since this question has apparently drawn some attention but doesn't have an accurate answer, I will go ahead and share what ultimately ended up being our best solutions. We currently use both of these solutions depending on which type of system we are deploying.*

*However, it basically means we need to abandon EFS for storing our **code**. It's just not the right tool for the job, and we have no regrets about abandoning it. If you still need to share non-code files between servers, then the best solution for that is probably to switch to using AWS S3 in combination with AWS CloudFront.*

---

### Solution 1:

*(Very easy to set up, but only works for some systems)*

If your system is compatible, then you should use [AWS Amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/). It is very easy to set up and basically takes care of everything in solution 2 for you. In our experience, this is particularly good for frontend ReactJS apps and completely handles global replication without needing to set up each region.

### Solution 2:

*(Works for most EC2-based systems, but is less optimized and requires more setup)*

Arguably, one of the best solutions for this is to combine [AWS CodeDeploy](https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/) and [AWS CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/). This will work for just about any codebase that runs on an EC2 instance.

- **CodeDeploy** allows you to use a service like GitHub to host your code centrally and then manually deploy specific commits to your EC2 server or auto-scaling group.
- **CodePipeline** allows you to automatically start a CodeDeploy whenever you commit to specific branches on GitHub. (As well as other things)

You will have to set up CodeDeploy and CodePipeline for each region you want to serve, but once they are configured all you have to do is push a commit to one of the specific branches and it will start deploying to every region all-at-once.

The result is not only good for making it easy to deploy code to multiple regions, but it also forces your production code to be managed by version control (easy rollbacks) and makes autoscaling more viable, but not required.

Side Note: **DO NOT** use "AWS CodeCommit" unless you have to for some reason. (IMO it is hot garbage and is more likely to cause issues than solve them)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EFS File Sync` which is AWS service.

You can sync between regions EFS File Sync agent in one AWS Region, and sync to an EFS file system in another AWS Region.

Pricing is $0.01 per GB copied to EFS + the space (storage) you are using on EFS on the new region

Comment: Unfortunately, EFS File Sync has been deprecated and replaced by another product called _DataSync_. It does not appear to have the ability to sync from EFS to EFS.

Comment: Use CloudFront (CDN) so the content will be cached for your users and no need to have multiple copies.